# multiple context property placeholder

Tags: spring, properties-file

can the order attribute be set to any value ( negative also ) . when I  have multiple context property place holders ,and  always want only a particular  context placeholder to always execute first - how do I acheive this

Comment: Why would order of loading properties matter?

Comment: Well! It does ! Ran into some issue while Building some spring based shared libraries!

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot delve  more into details

Comment: I wanted the context:property placeholder in  the shared library to be executed first before any other property loaders in the app context get executed